# Broadcast receiver not receiving Intent sent from WorkManager doWork()

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I'm trying to broadcast an intent from WorkManager, but the intent is not captured by Broadcast receiver.
If I send the same intent using `adb shell am broadcast -a Action` command, the intent is caught by the BroadcastReceiver.

```
  override fun doWork(): Result {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartJob: start periodic work")
    val intent = Intent(context, MyReceiver::class.java)
      .setAction(MyReceiver.SOME_ACTION)
    context.sendBroadcast(intent)
    return Result.success()
  }
```

Comment: It is likely that the activity you are trying to send the broadcast to is not created yet and therefore the broadcast becomes lost.

Comment: @MahirIslam you can't send a broadcast to an Activity.

Comment: Could you include a [mre]?